DNSSEC Configuration
I bought hosting for rizsolutions.com, my primary domain, via HosterPK. My local Linux environment hosts my subdomains, such as dev.rizsolutions.com, cloud.rizsolutions.com, and app.rizsolutions.com. Using Let's Encrypt, I have secured every web server with an SSL certificate and configured a DNS server on Windows Server 2016.
I now want to set up DNSSEC on HosterPK's cPanel and my Windows Server DNS. The main thing that worries me is if I should create the DNSSEC keys in HosterPK's cPanel and then copy them to my Windows DNS server, or if I should create the keys on my Windows server and copy them to HosterPK's cPanel? Is adding a DNSKEY item to the DNS records the proper way to configure DNSSEC, or is there another way?
Furthermore, I have observed that everything operates as intended when accessed internally, but it does not function correctly when accessed externally, such as when trying to visit web servers like portainer.dev.rizsolutions.com. To ensure a secure and compliant configuration, please provide the exact and up-to-date settings required for both systems.

"To ensure a secure and compliant configuration, please provide the exact and up-to-date settings required for both systems." - Is this your question or a message you receive?


The main thing that worries me is if I should create the DNSSEC keys in HosterPK's cPanel and then copy them to my Windows DNS server, or if I should create the keys on my Windows server and copy them to HosterPK's cPanel? Is

Having your own authoritative DNS server generally means that you won't be using the hosting provider's cPanel DNS management anymore – you cannot have the same DNS zone hosted in both places. (Well, you can, but it won't take a week before you have mismatching records and things start going wrong, so choose one or the other.)
The usual practice is that you generate a keypair on the system where it is to be used, and copy only the public key to other systems. (For example, when issuing HTTPS certificates, it is never the CA that generates a keypair for you – instead your server itself generates the keypair in whichever format it needs and provides only the public key for the CA to certify.)
The same applies to DNSSEC signing. If your own DNS server will be the one doing all signing, there is no reason for your domain registrar to ever have access to your private key (and I'm surprised it would even offer that option) – the registrar only needs the public key (of the KSK), which it'll publish for resolvers to find.
On the other hand, if HosterPK will be handling DNSSEC for you, then let them generate the keys.
You're not required to use the same keys throughout the lifetime of the domain; you can always migrate by publishing new keys (DS records) in preparation and removing the old DS at the end. (Usually that's easier than trying to decipher what kind of weird format Windows expects for private key import.) This means you can have both your own and HosterPK's keys published at the same time, but this should only be done for migration purposes.

Is adding a DNSKEY item to the DNS records the proper way to configure DNSSEC, or is there another way?

DNSKEY records on their own are meaningless; they only make sense together with the RRSIG "record signature" records that your DNS server would generate.
If you are using the "DNS Manager" MMC console, right-click your zone in the left panel and select "DNSSEC → Sign the Zone" to have it generate keys and sign all records within the zone. (It will automatically update the signatures on schedule and whenever you do any updates.)
Then look at the automatically-added DNSKEY records, specifically the "KSK" (flag value 257), and provide them to your registrar – either as full public key (DNSKEY) or converted to SHA256 fingerprint (DS) depending on what it requires (different TLD registries have different requirements, even though ultimately only a DS record gets published either way).

To ensure a secure and compliant configuration, please provide the exact and up-to-date settings required for both systems.

Don't write your questions via ChatGPT.
